# Mock file input as file path on Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking, sinatra

I have a question on how to use rspec to mock a file input. I have a following code for the class, but not exactly know a why to mock a file input. `filepath` is `/path/to/the/file`

I did my search on Google and usually turns out to be loading the actual file instead of mocking, but I'm actually looking the opposite where only mock, but not using the actual file.

```
module Service
  class Signing
    def initialize(filepath)
      @config = YAML.load_file(filepath)
      raise "Missing config file." if @config.nil?
    end

    def sign()      …
    end

    private
    def which()     …
    end

  end 
end
```

Is it possible to use EOF delimiter for this file input mocking?

```
file =  <<EOF
A_NAME: ABC
A_ALIAS: my_alias
EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stub out `YAML.load_file` and return parsed YAML from your text, like this:

```
yaml_text = <<-EOF
  A_NAME: ABC
  A_ALIAS: my_alias
EOF
yaml = YAML.load(yaml_text)
filepath = "bogus_filename.yml"
YAML.stub(:load_file).with(filepath).and_return(yaml)
```

This doesn't quite stub out the file load itself, but to do that you'd have to make assumptions about what YAML.load_file does under the covers, and that's not a good idea.  Since it's safe to assume that the YAML implementation is already tested, you can use the code above to replace the entire call with your parsed-from-text fixture.

If you want to test that the correct filename is passed to `load_file`, replace the stub with an expectation:

```
YAML.should_receive(:load_file).with(filepath).and_return(yaml)
```

Comment: But how did you actually stub it when calling new
`Service::Signing.new(filepath)` ?

I would like to test various bad yaml entry in the file and see it would raise an error

Comment: After the setup above, you can manipulate `Service::Signing` however you normally would, maybe something like `expect { Service::Signing.new(filepath) }.not_to raise_error`, for example.

Comment: Avoid deprecation warning by stubbing `YAML` using :

`allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with(filepath).and_return yaml`

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is to put an expectation on something, I don't see much benefit on this approach of calling `YAML.load` to fake the return. `YAML.load_file` actually returns a hash, so instead of doing all that my suggestion would be to simply return a hash:

```
parsed_yaml = { 
  "somekey" => {
    "someotherkey" => "abc"
  } 
}

YAML.should_receive(:load_file).with(filepath).and_return(parsed_yaml)
```

As this is supposed to be a unit test and not an integration test, I think this would make more sense.